# how to avoid carriage return (\r) during split javascript

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I am trying to convert csv to json but after spliting i am getting carriage return in output how to remove that.

### Input:

```
Country Name,Country Code,Indicator Name,Indicator Code
Afghanistan,AFG,"2005 PPP conversion factor, GDP (LCU per international $)",PA.NUS.PPP.05
```

Expected Result:

```
[{"Country Name":"Afghanistan","Country Code":"AFG","Indicator Name":"\"2005 PPP conversion factor, GDP (LCU per international $)\"","Indicator Code":"PA.NUS.PPP.05"}]
```

### Actual Result:

```
[{"Country Name":"Afghanistan","Country Code":"AFG","Indicator Name":"\"2005 PPP conversion factor, GDP (LCU per international $)\"","Indicator Code\r":"PA.NUS.PPP.05"}]
```

### code:

```
var currentline=lines[i].match(/(".*?"|[^",\s]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g);
```

Comment: This link may help you....[convert-csv-to-json](http://techslides.com/convert-csv-to-json-in-javascript)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sturtevant/AZFvQ/